# css table-cell has too much width

Tags: html, css

I have a table that looks like this:

```
+------------+---------------------------------+-----------------------+
|BUTTON      |            Text                 |BUTTON BUTTON          |
+------------+---------------------------------+-----------------------+
```

I want it too look like this:

```
+------+---------------------------------+-------------+
|BUTTON|            Text                 |BUTTON BUTTON|
+------+---------------------------------+-------------+
```

i.e. I want the outer columns to just be as wide as necessary based on it's content. And I want the inner content (the buttons) to line up next to each other?

...My best idea so far is to set a 1px width on the outer columns. But since the buttons are floated it ends up looking like this:

```
+------+---------------------------------+------+
|BUTTON|            Text                 |BUTTON|
|      |                                 |BUTTON|
+------+---------------------------------+------+
```

see this try on jsbin: http://jsbin.com/orayoy/1/edit

Thanks!

Comment: Try `display: inline-block;` instead of `float: left;` on `#c1` and `#c2`. And remove the `width: 100%` from `#box`.

Comment: Or if you want to keep the 100%: http://jsbin.com/orayoy/7/edit

Answer (score 2):

```
<td style="white-space: nowrap; width: 1px;">...</td>
```

On the 1st and 3rd columns. You MIGHT have to use a `&nbsp;` between the buttons in the 3rd col, not positive.

Answer (score 0):

example: http://jsbin.com/orayoy/8/edit

```
#box {
    display: table;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
#a {
    display: table-cell;
    background-color: lime;
}
#b {
    display: table-cell;
    background-color: blue;
}
#c {
    width: 1px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    display: table-cell;
    background-color: red;
}
#c1 {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: pink;
}
#c2 {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: pink;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you set the table width to "auto" it should base the width of the table on the content.